# Falling out with the Judge II

Tags: word, wordplay, cryptic-clues

> All by oneself: thrown out car, rotten feed, and amount of food found outside bird's house (18)

The bird was never found again, and no fingerprints could be found on the car or the food. What happened to the bird?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The bird...

> threw itself out of the window! i.e. It committed **[AUTODEFENESTRATION](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defenestration#Self-defenestration_or_autodefenestration)**.

Explanation:

> Definition is '*All by oneself: thrown out*'.
>
>  *car* = **AUTO**;
>
>  *rotten feed* = anagram of FEED = **DEFE**;
>
>  *amount of food* = **RATION**;
>
>  *found outside bird's house* = either side of **NEST**.
>
>  Put it all together, and you have **AUTO + DEFE + NEST + RATION**!

Comment: Time to find trickier ways to clue this :D